# ATmega2560 fast enough?

Tags: fpga, atmega, servo, motordriver

I want to drive a servo with the ATmega2560. I'm wonder if it can handle the 10 kHz encoder at full speed and the 3-phase chopper the driver has to operate (runs at 12 kHz).

Or do I need to start looking at FPFAs, and if so, where do I start? I'm familiar with programming an FPGA, just not with selectung the right one and the bits that are needed for it to operate.

I'm thinking the 12 kHz mossed driving, the 10 kHz encoder, and the step/DIR input are a bit much.

Maybe I can combine 2 or 3 processors, I'm not sure, so that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: There are other cheap and easy to program microcontrollers which run at 10x the speed of the 2560, eg. the rpi2040 or any of the teensy 3.x or 4.x boards.

Comment: RPI2040 might not be a great pick due to the lack of analog, but it's [definitely possible](https://github.com/Twisted-Fields/rp2040-motor-controller). There's a lot of processors between an ATMega and going to FPGAs. Something in the STM32 or ATSAM range would be the default - both have parts specifically designed for motor control.

Comment: so your saying the atmega isnt gonna cut it and i should look at one of the once you listed above?

Comment: Your ATmega seems a bit weak. But you certainly don't need an FPGA. We've implemented a BL DC drive with a [TM4C123FH6PM](https://www.ti.com/product/TM4C123FH6PM#order-quality) and an AC Servo with a [TM4C1294NCPDT](https://www.ti.com/product/TM4C1294NCPDT?keyMatch=TM4C1294NCPDT&tisearch=search-everything&usecase=GPN).

Comment: OK from the chips listed above I'm going to go with the rpi2040 since it seems to be the only available one, thanks for the help guys. If I have more questions, ill be sure to ask 'em here 
such fast responses!

Comment: @AlanvandeGlind as said, Rpi2040 might not be the appropriate choice. Really, there's a wealth of STM32 series chips that would actually help you.

Comment: @AlanvandeGlind and you'll find that there's plenty STM32 and ATSAM available, see https://nl.farnell.com/w/c/semiconductors-ics/microcontrollers/arm-microcontrollers/prl/resultaten?device-core=arm-cortex-m3|arm-cortex-m33|arm-cortex-m33f|arm-cortex-m4|arm-cortex-m4-arm-cortex-m0pos|arm-cortex-m4f|arm-cortex-m4f-arm-cortex-m0pos|arm-cortex-m7|arm-cortex-m7f|arm-cortex-m7f-arm-cortex-m0pos|arm-cortex-m4-arm-cortex-m7&range=inc-in-stock|exc-delivery-surcharge|inc-in-stock%7Cexc-delivery-surcharge&sort=P_PRICE as an example (extrapolating shipping location from name, hope that's OK). All these

Comment: 304 results (as of writing) are better for your application than the RP2040, considering that they include memory for the program itself. The RP2040 needs external components to be useful at all!

Comment: I was content using an ATSAM4S in this context. Done this with ATmega128 before, but needed a lot of raw assembly code.

Comment: Microchip has a [page of MCUs they recommend for motor control.](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/solutions/motor-control-and-drive/motor-control-products/32-bit-microcontrollers-for-motor-control-applications)